# is var++ = 0 a valid expression in bash?

Tags: bash

I tried to organize homebrew packages with bash alias:

`alias brewUses='brew list | while read cask; do let var=var+1 && echo -en "$var\033[1m $cask \033[0m \033[34mUSED BY : \033[0m"; brew uses --installed $cask | awk '"'"'{printf "  \033[4m%s\033[0m  ", $0}'"'"'; echo ""; done'`

this is the final version of my line -- without error, sample output:

[image]

What I want to ask is:

1. is `var++ = 0` doesn't work in bash?
2. is there a better way to generate the number in front of each line? Such as something hidden from `brew list | while read cask` rather than *hard*-code `let var=var+1`
3. what is the exact reason, that there's error `` -bash: syntax error near unexpected token `(' `` every time i use `((...))` in the line

## Edit:

Snippet credit: [MH Nichols](http://zanshin.net/2014/02/03/how-to-list-brew-dependencies/)

Comment: What exactly do you imagine `var++ = 0` would do?

Comment: My bad. Some part in my blur memory told me that it's a shorthand of `var = 0 ; var++ `. I may be wrong, thank you.

Comment: @JustinMoh: Shorthand for `var=0; ((var++))` is `var=1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a counter, sure. `x++` only works in arithmetic context.

```
line=0
brew list | while read -r cask; do
    (( line++ ))
    …
done
```

Or you could

```
brew list | cat -n | while read line cask; do
    …
done
```

(By the way, a shell function would be much more maintainable than an alias here. Here's how I would write it):

```
brewUses() {
    local line cask uses
    brew list | while read cask; do
        uses=( $(brew uses --installed "$cask") )
        printf '%02d\033[1m %s \033[0m' $(( ++line )) "$cask"
        if (( ${#uses[@]} )); then
            printf '\033[34mUSED BY:'
            printf '\033[0m \033[4m%s' "${uses[@]}"
        fi
        printf '\033[0m\n'
    done
}
```

Comment: I agree a custom shell function is better for some more complicated than this. Thanks